# Between operator transfered phone numbers not receiving sent sms by twilio where UNDELIVERED status is RETURNED

Tags: twilio

In Morocco we have 3 operators:
 => IAM, INWI and ORANGE
 => My personal phone number was originally purchased from IAM operator then i have transfered it to INWI (and this is the problem)

I am integrating Twilio in my software and have made some tests and observed this when sending a new sms to someone :
 - If the phone number is normal (not transfered as in my case) the SMS is delivered correctly
 - If the phone number is transfered from an operator to an other as in my case the SMS is not Delivered

Am i missing any config or something ?

I am testing with postman via post http call to Twilio REST API url :
https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts//Messages.json

Comment: This doesn't sound like a coding problem, instead I would get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and share with them some message SIDs that didn't get delivered. They will then track down with the carrier what happened to the message.

Comment: I used clickatell.com and it works by default. So twilio does not look reliable

Comment: I am glad you got it to work with a provider. Working with operators across the world is a challenge which we try to rise to. I would really appreciate if you could still contact Twilio support with your example messages so that we can track what has gone wrong in our system. Sorry it hasn't been a great experience for you though.